# tkiner output isnt on the same pop-up window

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay so what I'm trying to figure out is how to control the location of output.
Currently when you run the code a window comes up and allows you to type into a label "manual". with the option to press enter or click the 'submit' button. The typed entry is then put in a new pop-up window every time I.e. Input1(test) and input2(testing) will show up in separate windows. How do I set it so it shows up in the same pop-up window preferably spaced on the y axis so it isn't cluttered. As this is a manual entry there is no telling how many entries will be submitted and it may be possible once so many entries have been entered it will need to move over on the X axis and start again at the top of the Y axis.

I'd also like to know how to pick where the pop-up ends up on the screen I tried using
`win.place(x=200, y=50)` but the `.Toplevel()` doesn't have an attribute of `.place()`

```py
import tkinter as tk

#function that prints the entry
def entry_function(e=None):
    name = entry.get()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
    win.geometry('100x100')

 #Setup for the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.bind('<Return>', entry_function)


#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Manual:", bg = "dark grey", fg = "white")
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text = "submit",
                   command = entry_function)

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For displaying the entry on same popup, you can use the below code for entry function

```
import tkinter as tk

flag = False
win=""

def setflag(event):
    global flag
    flag = False
    
#function that prints the entry
def entry_function(e=None):
    global flag,win
    name = entry.get()
    if not flag:
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        win.geometry('100x100')
        win.bind('<Destroy>', setflag)
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
        flag = True
        win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 200, y + 50))
    else:
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
     

 #Setup for the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.bind('<Return>', entry_function)
x = window.winfo_x()
y = window.winfo_y()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
x_cord = int((sw/2)-550)
y_cord = int((sh/2)-300)
wh = 550
ww = 1100
window.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(ww, wh, x_cord, y_cord))


#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Manual:", bg = "dark grey", fg = "white")
entry = tk.Entry(window)
button = tk.Button(window,text = "submit",
                   command = entry_function)

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `open` as a variable name, especially in this case

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Matiiss. forgot it was a function

Comment: @liquiddeath Okay I've got a few questions about the code you've added. I don't get line3-8 where you create a var named flag set to False and then again in setflag function create this time a global flag set to False. I get l3 is local but why does it need both instead of initially calling it as global outside of the function. I also tried to implement line 20s geometry format in line 28 (window.geometry) with no luck literally just copying the line and setting it to window>win. But yeah if you could explain these few things I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @navi when you define a variable outside of a function, by default it is a global variable, but here in this case we need to modify the flag value, to do that you need to define the variable as global inside the function where you are doing the modification. to read a variable you need not to do that.  l3 is not local it is global. setflag() function is binded to the destroy method of popup window, so every time you close it the flag will be set to false, allowing us to open it again. line 20 defines where to position the popup respective to the main window.

Comment: @liquiddeath Wow your explanation hit some light bulbs. Okay so if I understand. . The setflag function is what actually allows the popup to "clear" the information entered when you close the popup(win) .Along with the L17 ```win.bind('<Destroy>', setflag)``` which is the actual "clear" when (win) is closed and then the "reset" on L19setting ```flag = True``` is where you re allow the (win) to temporarily store the outputs from entry widget until closed.

Comment: @navi yes right. your last question "I also tried to implement line 20s geometry format in line 28 " if you meant to place the main window at a position, i have updated it in the answer. modify the values as per your need

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the popup once and add label to it inside `entry_function()`.

You can make the popup hidden initially and show it inside `entry_function()` and you can specify the position of the popup using `geometry()`.

```py
def entry_function(e=None):
    MAX_ROWS = 20  # adjust this value to suit your case
    name = entry.get().strip()
    if name:
        n = len(popup.winfo_children())
        tk.Label(popup, text=name).grid(row=n%MAX_ROWS, column=n//MAX_ROWS, sticky='nsew', ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        popup.deiconify()  # show the popup
        window.focus_force()  # give focus back to main window

...
# create the popup
popup = tk.Toplevel()
popup.withdraw() # hidden initially
popup.geometry('+100+100') # place the popup to where ever you want
popup.title("Log Window")
popup.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', popup.withdraw) # hide popup instead of destroying it
...
```